# Looks like ECB -- What story is this?

Tags: cipher

### Secrets Revisited

A friend sent me the following and wanted to find out if anyone could figure it out. The message was encrypted three times, and all keys and primers were provided. It appears that there are some fairly obvious patterns that might be exploitable. The plaintext is not necessary for the answer, just the name of the story. Kudos go to whoever can explain how the keys and primers relate to the given ciphertext.

---

**Key 1:**

```
xmjfdlzquaoyvbkswcipnehrtg
bctmalxrhknjgqfvdusyieopwz
jqkywbacpdlmofusthzxiengrv
```

**Key 2:**

```
HRCXYEPMWDLQFAOGBVZKNSJTUI
ZJWPNHXYQOGDISKRACVLTUBEFM
JFYXASMZWKDOCQEIHNGBTUVLRP
```

**Key 3:**

```
%"'>^\#[<&~_();+:.}]$?{/!@,`|=*-
%:!?;~]$@'+.-*)}=&>{(<[|_#\^/,`"
#}[._`!":%(\@>+?&{^]'$=*,)<~/;|-
```

---

**Primer 1:** `tk`

**Primer 2:** `ZA`

**Primer 3:** `_?`

---

**Ciphertext:**

```
O qc Mkh"
Ikh J kh)

Reno Zxv)T;kh!
Reno Zxv\T.kh!
B cv kwv crnd neoo Kxv\G.kh!

Qj tgq tsnd qnuhg klak ypg tef)

Y cv kwv crnd nekg= Ojh-G:kh\
B cv kwv crnd qnuhg klak ypg tef^

Tjnto bjq tsnd nekg atds zr hmkds?

O kmdto jpv crnd nekg atds zr hmkds|
Z kmdto jpv crnd nekg jrnjmuds)
D ei kwv crnd qnuhg klak ypg tef;
D cv kwv crnd nekg( Kjh%G:kh\

Yjnto bjq tsnd nekg oz b oxmlt_
Cwxto bjq tsnd nekg tsht o fjnlt>

T li kwv crnd nekg oz b oxmlt`
Z li kwv crnd nekg tsht o fjnlt)
D li kwv crnd nekg atds zr hmkds;
D ei kwv crnd nekg jrnjmuds;
D ei kwv crnd qnuhg klak ypg tef;
D cv kwv crnd nekg( Kjh%G:kh\

Yjnto bjq cka plkg oz b dnn_
Cjato bjq cka plkg tsht o hux>

Cju kh b dnn`
Mju jlht o hux)
Rju kh b oxmlt;
Rwg jlht o fjnlt;
J tmdto jpv oha plkg atds zr hmkds;
F kmdto jpv oha plkg jrnjmuds;
D kmdto jpv oha zduhg klak ypg tef;
D cv kwv crnd nekg( Kjh%G:kh\

Yjnto bjq' sctto bjq- ek b lbl~
Lrs plkg. Tjf plkg' Jzrs yeky pkm]

M kmdto jpv+ ugtto jpv- kh b lbl>

Dyz gdu wnnd nekg: Hwn arkp uqz;
Kxx gdu wnnd nekg oz b hcgh"

X umdto jpv; ugtto jpv' kh b hcgh>
Mxg kh b lbl> Dyz tyw xw qt:
A zi kwv crnd nekg oz b dnn.
C cm kwv crnd nekg tsht o hux;
D cm kwv crnd nekg oz b oxmlt;
D li kwv crnd nekg tsht o fjnlt;
D li kwv crnd nekg atds zr hmkds;
D ei kwv crnd nekg jrnjmuds;
D ei kwv crnd qnuhg klak ypg tef;
D cv kwv crnd nekg( Kjh%G:kh\

W qgedt/ W ziedt> J ziedt# J ziedt#
Umbto bjq. afdto bjq' me j hcedt~

Imv kh b hcedt. Nmv kh b hcgh'
Rxg kh b lbl# Pru. gfw xw qt/
Z gmdto jpv: ugtto jpv' kh b dnn>
B wttto jpv; jydto jpv- jlht o hux>
D odkp fav oha plkg tsht o fjnlt:
D tekp fav oha plkg oz b oxmlt;
D tekp fav oha plkg atds zr hmkds;
D kekp fav oha plkg jrnjmuds;
D ei kwv crnd qnuhg klak ypg tef;
D cv kwv crnd nekg( Kjh%G:kh\

Hku/ Gi ouk wdjq/ Gqis xv zuk wdjq}
Bcsto bjq) sctto bjq' ek zuk wdjq~

U gwdto jpv| ugtto jpv* kh zuk wdjq>

Pcsto bjq; sctto bjq- ek zuk dydt~

O akdto jpv| ugtto jpv kh zuk dydt%
Tmv kh zuk wdjq: Uck nf j hcedt;
Rmv kh b lbl; Ryl kh b hcgh;
J si kwv crnd nekg( Jjh- vmq ltz>
Nxg kh b oxmlt: Ewg kh b dnn;
Rju jlht o fjnlt; Rwg jlht o hux;
J odkp fav oha plkg atds zr hmkds;
F ei kwv crnd nekg jrnjmuds"

Izx wn kwv crnd qnuhg klak ypg tef/

L cv kwv crnd nekg= Fjh-G:kh\

Ljnto bjq' afdto bjq- arht o rfgm~

P hydto jpv| ugtto jpv* jlht o rfgm{

Kkoto bjq: sctto bjq' me j dnrm~

O jgtto jpv| jydto jpv* nf j dnrm>
Z hlkp fav; jlkp fav- jlht o rfgm>
D hlkp fav oha plkg oz zuk dydt:
D aukp fav oha plkg wb j hcedt;
Omv kh zuk wdjq" Uck kh b hcgh>
Rxg kh b lbl# Fyz tyw xw qt#
A zi kwv crnd nekg oz b dnn]
C cm kwv crnd nekg tsht o hux.
D odkp fav oha plkg oz b oxmlt;
D li kwv crnd nekg tsht o fjnlt;
D li kwv crnd nekg atds zr hmkds;
D ei kwv crnd nekg RSTRPMQR"
Y lv kwv crnd qnuhg klak ypg tef>
O cv kwv crnd nekg. Kjh>G:kh\

Pjn wn kwv crnd nekg' nx ngq lnd"
Shw ijkg> Fpf ijkg> Wsq sjq gdu]
Dhw ijkg jrg sjq gdu+ J rgd"

Rla> Gp xdq arkp mnw xw qt;
B gekp awp ijkg^ Iwn arkp uqz:
Nvk" W wnnd qnuhg klak ypg tef>
B cv# D vlnd nekg. Kjh>G:kh!
Wmq B bhdto pqa plkg oz b dnrm#
Gbr B bhdto pqa plkg tsht o rfgm.
Gbr B bwkp nra plkg oz zuk dydt;
Gxx gq zuk wdjq; Wwj lk j hcedt;
Jxx gq b lbl; Jop gq b hcgh;
Gpdy pkm oz jabm( km jabm- njq ltz{
Px T jbkp nra plkg oz b dnn}
Wmh B bwkp nra plkg tsht o hux.
Gmh B eqa plkg oz b oxmlt;
Gsb B bwkp nra plkg tsht o fjnlt;
Gsb B bwkp nra plkg atds ifg owkds;
Mik" G mjkp nra plkg WSTRPMQR>
Y lv pt qlnd qnuhg klak ypg tef#
Iendz uhq# Knjdz uhq. Hbd>T:kh!
```

Comment: What is a "primer" in this context? You mentioned them in your other puzzle as well. A google search for "cryptography primer" yields nothing using the word to mean anything besides "a short introductory piece of writing on a subject"

Comment: Does this require a computer to decrypt, and is the decryption process something you came up with? (In other words, are we just shooting in the dark as to how the ciphertext came about?)

Comment: @Otaia It was revealed that a primer is also called an initialization vector.

Comment: @Emrakul After seeing the work others have accomplished with cryptograms around here, I believe that the repeating nature of the ciphertext will be its breaking point, and the encryption process will not need to be understood. However, if the source of the text is discovered, then a foothold may be gained for those trying to understand it.

Comment: @NoctisSkytower Indeed the nature of the ciphertext gave it away, specifically the repetitions, word breaks and formatting. I figured out what story it is, still working on the encryption method

Comment: @CDspace It was slightly surprising to see this solved so quickly! According to my schedule, an explanation of the prototype encryption system should follow in a little less than five weeks. I would love to provide examples with smaller keys and primers but am afraid that the method would become too obvious.

Comment: @CDspace Did the published explanation of the encryption method make any sense?

Comment: I don't see any explanation of the method, but by comparing the given plain and cipher texts I've concluded that it is a kind of autokey cipher where each letter of the ciphertext is uniquely determined by the corresponding letter of the plaintext together with the previous two plain letters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The story is

> Green Eggs and Ham, by Dr. Seuss.

Comment: I imagine you got that just by looking at the ciphertext and its word lengths and repetitions?

Comment: Yes. I'm afraid I don't understand the encryption method.

Comment: Do you understand the encryption method now that an explanation has been published?